# dart - mocks, methodnames called by name, refactoring fails

Tags: mocking, dart, dart-mirrors

I have used the dart unittest framework and the included Mock class [as described](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mocking-with-dart/)

There is however a dependency in the mock calls i.e:

```dart
..store.when(callsTo('isLocked')).thenReturn(false);
```

where the call to the `isLocked` method is called by name. If someone renamed the `isLocked` method the refactoring framework will not rename the call.

I was wondering if reflection (mirrors) could help somehow, but I haven't found a solution.

Cheers
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the method I ended up using is a constant class with method names. Like so:

```dart
class MethodNames{
  final String GET_ELEMENT = 'getElement';
  final String GET_CLASSES = 'get classes';
  final String SET_DISABLED = 'set:disabled';
  final String AS_INPUT = 'asInput';
  final String AS_BUTTON = 'asButton';
  final String SET_INNER_HTML = 'set:innerHTML';
  final String SET_VALUE = 'set:value';
...
  const MethodNames();
}
```

I has the advantage of being nice and simple. I tend to prefer that.

cheers
Peter

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I try to avoid mocking classes (unless they make use of external resources, like RESTful web APIs) specifically because of this problem. If class A mocks out class B's foo method, but class B has actually renamed its foo method fooBar, your tests will still pass. However, when class A tries to call B.foo at runtime, things will crash. Hence, I avoid mocking anything that is available locally.

Fortunately, the situation is a little bit better in Dart than it is in other dynamic languages. For instance, you can create a class that implements another class. So if FakeB implements B, then you can add functions to FakeB that can be used when testing A.

Naturally, it's a bit much for the refactoring framework to know that your code callsTo('isLocked') actually refers to some method named isLocked which has actually been renamed isReallyLocked. However, I think you're on the right path with looking at the mirrors API. For instance, it'd be great if you could write callsTo(isLocked.**name**). That way the VM could provide more checking for your mocks.

Naturally, the real goal is to get the test to fail when the APIs don't match up. I did some playing with the mirrors API, and the best I could come up with is:

```dart
#import('dart:io');
#import("dart:mirrors");

void a() {
  print("a");
}

void main() {
  String thisFile = "file://${new Directory.current().path}/${new Options().script}";
  print(currentMirrorSystem().libraries[thisFile].functions['a'].simpleName);
}
```

This code still uses "a" as a string, but it has the benefit that if "a" doesn't exist as a function, it'll blow up. It's kind of ugly and hacky, but it's going in the direction of what you were looking for.

Another thing that you could do is something like:

```dart
when(callsTo('isLocked')).alwaysCall(isLocked)
```

In this case, the mocking system is just playing a middle man between the caller and the isLocked function. There are two downsides to this approach: a) presumably you were trying to completely avoid calling isLocked at all, otherwise you wouldn't be using a mocking framework b) isLocked is duplicated, first as a string, and then as a function. However, it does have a couple benefits: a) it lets you record the fact that isLocked is being called b) it won't work if isLocked is renamed; i.e. the person who renames isLocked will see this code, and hopefully update both places.

Another "brute force" approach is as follows:

```dart
void a() {
  print("a");
}

String makeSureItExists(obj, String name) {
  return obj != null ? name : "NoSuchMethod";   
}

void main() {
  print(makeSureItExists(a, "a"));
}
```

This lets you write something like callsTo(makeSureItExists(login, "login")).

Comment: I don't think you are getting the point (or I am not getting your point) : (callsTo('isLocked')).thenReturn(false) actually tells the mock class to return false when the method 'isLocked' is called. When I rename isLocked in the original class the refactoring framework should rename the mocked method also.

Comment: Gryffe, if you agree, perhaps you'll be so kind as to hit the up arrow on my answer ;)